# How To Use A Custom Library?

Tags: c#, static-libraries

I want to use compression of some files but GZipStream can not archive many files in one zip only! So I want to use this

> http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/

But I have no idea how to install/use/import custom libraries. What should I do?

Comment: That page has a donwload link, after that you follow the manual for your favorite IDE, for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Or use nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click your project and select "Manage NuGet Packages..."

Search for "SharpZipLib".

When it populates the list, install it

The installation process should add the necessary reference[s] to your project's References folder

You might then need to add a "using" for the library to the class where you want to add the code. It's possible, though, that you can just right-click the code and select "Resolve" to have the "using" automatically added for you.

Then look at the library authors' documentation for usage.

Comment: what is the best compression? is there a better than .zip ?